# Make search query more powerful

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have the following search engine:

HTML code:

```
<form id="header-search" action="car-list.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $_GET['search'];  ?>"  id="text" placeholder="Zoek hier.." class="quick-search" onchange  >

            <select name="type-option">
                <option value="auto" selected="selected">Auto's</option>
        <!--    <option value="bikes">Motoren</option>
                <option value="trucks">Trucks</option>
                <option value="Parts">Parts</option> -->
            </select>
            <div class="search-submit">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="search" value="Zoeken"/>
                 <input type="hidden" name="page" id="text"  value="1" class="quick-search"  >
                 <input type="hidden" name="ipp" id="text" value="25"  class="quick-search"  >
            </div>
        </form>
```

Php code:

```
<?php
$searchq = $_GET['search']; 
$searchq = htmlspecialchars($searchq); 
 $searchq = mysql_real_escape_string($searchq);                  
 $photo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `adver` WHERE merk LIKE '%$searchq%' OR titel 
 LIKE '%$searchq%' OR model LIKE '%$searchq%' ORDER BY car_id DESC $pages->limit")or die(mysql_error());

 while($get_photo=mysql_fetch_array($photo)){ 

?>

 <a href="<?php echo 'car-details.php?merk='.$get_photo['merk'] .'&car_id='  .$get_photo['car_id'] .'&titel=' .$get_photo['titel'] ;?>">
 <img src="<?php  echo $get_photo['path'] ; ?>"   style="border:1px solid #021a40;" alt="<?php  echo $get_photo['merk'] ;?>" }/>
```

I have one table. There are 3 columns `model, merk, titel`.

Let us say `model = Audi` and `merk = A6`. When I search for results for "Audi" or "A6" I get the results, but when I search for Audi A6, I'm getting no results back.

So I want a combination of two columns from the same `$Row`. How can I do this?

Comment: Dude... sql injection.  Look it up.

Comment: Also XSS `<input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $_GET['search'];  ?>" ....>` if user would search `"><script>alert('xss');</script>`

Comment: Thanks, But im using
$searchq = mysql_real_escape_string($searchq); 
Is that not enough to prevent sql injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your tables start to get larger, with a LIKE query and the % joker before the search-string, MySQL won't be able to use indexes and would do a full table scan. The query can become painfully slow. If you're using MyISAM tables, the best option would be to [create a Full-Text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) containing the searchable columns.

Then you have three types of [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) modes. Performance should be great with the con of not being able to use a joker anymore.

EDIT: Just read, that Full-Text search should be available for InnoDB too since MySQL 5.6

Comment: Hi, Thanks for youre information!
I'm going to read full-text-search!

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the fields you want to search:

```
$photo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `adver` WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',model,merk) LIKE '%$searchq%' ORDER BY car_id DESC $pages->limit")or die(mysql_error());
```

doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Comment: Im getting the fowllowing error:

FUNCTION register-login.ws_concat does not exist